# how to use counter in awk

Tags: arrays, unix, if-statement, awk

i have this input  for example

```
jak   101 98   
jon   101 97 
aiden 102 81
sam   105 77 
bob   106 55  
jo    102 96  
mik   103 91  
hanna 125 20  
mode  102 49  
anna  101 82 
...
..
.
.
```

.and so to 1200 student (what i need is the number of 101..102..103 and the  10        student who have the most higher grads

look like this out put

```
101 have :3 student the higher score is  jak ==98,jon==97,aiden==81    (but i need to most 10  ) ...........
102 have :2 student the higher score is  81,49
103 have :1 student the higher score is  91
105 have :1 student the higher score is 77
106 have :1 student the higher score is 55 
125 have :1 student the higher score is 20
```

Comment: thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk 'count[$2]++<10 { 
    stats[$2]=(stats[$2])?stats[$2]","$3:$3
}
END {
    for(x in count) {
        printf "%d have :%d student the higher score is %s\n",x,count[x],stats[x]
    }
}' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ cat file
jak   101 98   
jon   101 97 
aiden 102 81
sam   105 77 
bob   106 55  
jo    102 96  
mik   103 91  
hanna 125 20  
mode  102 49  
anna  101 82
```

```
$ awk 'count[$2]++<10 { 
    stats[$2]=(stats[$2])?stats[$2]","$3:$3
}
END {
    for(x in count) {
        printf "%d have :%d student the higher score is %s\n",x,count[x],stats[x]
    }
}' file
101 have :3 student the higher score is 98,97,82
102 have :3 student the higher score is 81,96,49
103 have :1 student the higher score is 91
105 have :1 student the higher score is 77
106 have :1 student the higher score is 55
125 have :1 student the higher score is 20
```

#### Update:

To include the student name, use the following:

```
awk 'count[$2]++<10 { 
    stats[$2]=(stats[$2])?stats[$2]","$1"="$3:$1"="$3
}
END {
    for(x in count) {
        printf "%d have :%d student the higher score is %s\n",x,count[x],stats[x]
    }
}' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ awk 'count[$2]++<10 { 
    stats[$2]=(stats[$2])?stats[$2]","$1"="$3:$1"="$3
}
END {
    for(x in count) {
        printf "%d have :%d student the higher score is %s\n",x,count[x],stats[x]
    }
}' file
101 have :3 student the higher score is jak=98,jon=97,anna=82
102 have :3 student the higher score is aiden=81,jo=96,mode=49
103 have :1 student the higher score is mik=91
105 have :1 student the higher score is sam=77
106 have :1 student the higher score is bob=55
125 have :1 student the higher score is hanna=20
```

Comment: thank you jaypal but i edit the qeustoin  i want the name of student to can you edit your answer so can i try it  thank you a lot

Comment: It wasn't clear on your question but if you want top 10 scores only then sort your file first using `sort -nk2,2 -nk3,3 file`